# Detect user's confirmation of iPhone call link?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, telprompt

The following code, if triggered by a button press in an app, presents the user with a `UIAlertView` giving them the option to "Cancel", and dismiss the `UIAlertView`, or "Call" and go through with dialing the number displayed to the user:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://555-555-5555"]];
```

My question is: Is there a way to detect whether or not the user followed through with actually dialing the number? I am implementing Google "Analytics" in my app to see how users are interacting with it, and I can track when they tap the `UIButton` that calls the code above, but that doesn't necessarily mean they actually made the call.

Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to check the user dialed that specific number. But you will be able to check they dialed a number using CTCallCenter:setCallEventHandler:

If they made a call immediately after you present the view its 99.9% reasonable to assume it was that number.

But also your app delegate's willResignActive will get called if they place the call and get connected (I think, I can't remember exactly) so you could use that as an indication.